# Angular CLI - 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, angular-cli

I installed Angular CLI version:7.3.5, Node Server version: v8.12.0 and NPM version 6.9.0, but when I run any ng command on Windows command prompt, it shows an error like:

```
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

When I run any ng command on VS Code terminal, I get an error like:

```
bash: ng: command not found
```

My ng command is only working on Node.js command prompt.

Comment: Does the npm command work?

Comment: Yes, npm command works properly.

Comment: When you installed Angular, did you do a local install (into the project) or a global install (using the `-g` flag)? You need to latter if you want to run ng from any location (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli#installation).

Comment: i just installed Angular globally used -g flag.

Answer (score 1):

That usually means you don't have node or you didn't install the angular CLI. First make sure you have node. If you just installed it sometimes you just have to restart your machine. Then run:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: node and angular CLI are installed and work properly.